# How to pass data from background.js into app using Manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, svelte

I am exporting an global object variable from background.js in order to import it into my main.js file.

The data is being gathered in background.js using chrome.tabs.query.

However, if I add the export keyword to the variable in background.js and attempt to install the extension, it gives an error saying "Service worker registration failed" (no additional info). Removing the export keyword causes the error to not be thrown.

How can I pass the data through to the rest of the extension?

Alternatively, is there a way to gather information about the current tab, host name, and tab title from within the extension (without using background.js)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The background script runs in a separate service worker so you can't export anything directly. Instead, use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Note that the service worker lives only for 30 seconds so your global variables will be lost (the solution is to use `chrome.storage.local`).

Comment: Thanks! @wOxxOm
It is possible to still get the info in the background script using chrome.tabs.query and then send it to the rest of the extension using messaging, or should I get the info in a content script? Note that chrome.tabs.query cannot be used outside of [background](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#get-the-current-tab)

I also want it to re-query the data whenever the user changes tab, opens a new tab, or navigates to a new URL in their current tab.